# Custom Event Track Google Tag Manager using REST API

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to add Track an analytics custom event to my nodejs file. Is there any ways to do using REST api.
The Equivalent of this using REST API:

analytics.track('customEvent', {
label: 'lorem',
price: 20
})

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol that allows developers to make HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1

Comment: The question pertains to GTM, where events can be sent to other integrations. Sending directly to GA isn't always the best solution for businesses, depending on their needs.

Comment: So what do you propose as an alternative @AdrianoResende ?